# IIS 7.5 - Virtual directory mapped to Azure File Share - Cannot read configuration file

Tags: azure, iis-7.5, azure-storage, unc

As the title suggests I am receiving an error "Cannot read configuration file" when attempting to read a JPG file from an Azure File share mounted on a VM (from within Azure network) through a virtual directory from within IIS 7.5

This points to a permission problem - I created a local user on the web server matching the username and set the password to the Access Key of the storage service on Azure (the same credentials to access/mount the file storage share).

I set this on the app pool the vdir runs under aswell as the virtual directory properties "Physical Path Credentials" - both still return the following error:

**HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:

Module
   IIS Web Core

Notification
   BeginRequest

Handler
   Not yet determined

Error Code
   0x80070003

Config Error
   Cannot read configuration file

Config File
   \?\X:\web.config

Requested URL
   http://localhost:80/myvdir/1.jpg

Physical Path
   X:\1.jpg

Logon Method
   Not yet determined

Logon User
   Not yet determined

Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:

So either the credentials i'm using do not match the UNC credentials or IIS does not support this.

Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE - 2016-15-18**

***Solved***

Thanks to Simon W and Forester123

The issue was due to the following missing steps:

- When adding the local user I failed to add this user to the IIS_IUSRS group
- Using the drive letter at the start of the physical path for the application. You must use the UNC path \myaccount.file.core.windows.net\sharename you cannot use a drive letter e.g. X:\

This URL (provided by Simon W) was invaluable http://blogs.iis.net/davidso/azurefile

Comment: Do you have a specific need to use a file share within the storage account? If not then personally I would probably be using a VHD in blob storage mounted to the VM.

Comment: @MartynC what are the benefits to that approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to use a mapped drive is likely your issue. Take a look at how this is achieved using a UNC instead: http://blogs.iis.net/davidso/azurefile

Comment: Changing to UNC path instead of mapped drive, and ensuring the local user was in the right group solved it - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the UNC path of your file share as the **Physical Path** property:

```
\\<your_storage_account>.file.core.windows.net\<your_share>
```

[image]

Using mapped drive will just give the error you encountered. Mapped drive is only for the local user session. See below test:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes thats exactly same error I was getting - ensuring UNC path instead of the drive path and ensuring the user was in the right group fixed it